# React allow server side rendering for some urls

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router, github-pages, react-router-dom

I'm creating a user level GitHub page using React but want to allow child repos to create their own GitHub pages outside of the root app. How can I tell React to let specific routes not defined in the router fall through for server side rendering?

Comment: use `<a href=` instead of a `<Link` ?

Comment: That's what I'm currently using and it gets picked up by react. Added link to original question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling `unregister` on the react service worker which resolved this issue. The links themselves stayed as an `anchor` tag.